# How to work with luatex from git

Tags: luatex, format-files, git, lualatex-dev

I have TL2019 installed. Is it possible to clone and build the latest luatex from git, rebuild the lualatex format, and then work with that instead of TL2019's own lualatex? I'm specifically interested in LuaTeX 1.12.0. (Lualatex-dev in TL2019 is based on LuaHBTeX 1.11.2)

Comment: Why don't you install texlive 2020? https://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html

Comment: @Mark Is there a reason why you want to use the git mirror instead of the official SVN repo?

Comment: If you are on 64-bit Linux, you can just use my experimental LuaTeX repo.  Instructions how to use it are on the GitHub page: https://github.com/hmenke/texlive-luatex-dev

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer That is more than I was looking for, but is interesting in itself.

Comment: @Marcel Krüger No.

Comment: @Henri Menke That would be it. At the moment the curl gives me a 404, though.

Comment: @MarkvanAtten Oh, I forgot to update the README.  You can skip the curl step, the repo is no longer signed.

Comment: @Henri Menke OK, now it works.